# jQuery: Scroll to newly appended element?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to automatically scroll to the bottom of a new element? I saw the scrollTo plugin but it is a few years old. Is there a way to do this with the base jQuery api?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$('body, html').css("scrollTop", $("#new_element").offset().top);
```

If you want it 'animated' you could do this

```
$('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $("#new_element").offset().top }, 1000);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

More dynamic way by extending @Edgar Villegas Alvarado's solution:

```
    var htmlObject = $("<p>sample text</p>");

    $('#container').append(htmlObject);
    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $(htmlObject).offset().top }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard JavaScript `scrollTo` function, and get the position of the new element with jQuery's `offset`. Something along the lines of this should get you started:

```
window.scrollTo(0, $("#newElem").offset().top);
```

Here is an example showing it working :

```js
var newElem = "<div style='width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#ff0000; margin-top:500px' id='newElem'></div>";
$("body").append(newElem);
window.scrollTo(0, $("#newElem").offset().top);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erCEq/2/)